# Architecture missing x86-64 in file

Tags: xcode

My app has been working fine for several weeks, but today I accidentally deleted my architecture in xcode, and now I can't get it to work again.
I have been seeing similar problems here on stack, but so far the solutions has not worked for me.

I get this error:

missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/**/Desktop/APP/RecipeBookParseUpdate/Parse.framework/Parse (3 slices)

I can't remember what architecture I was using before when it was working fine...

Comment: Are you using `git`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: I just looked Git up, and I dont think I am, as I had not heard of it before. I am fairly new to xcode and programming, so I might without knowing then..